# TypeScript Class Not Found by IntelliSense or Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, google-closure-compiler, javascript-intellisense

Consider the following TypeScript file:

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() { }
    execute(): void { }
}
```

This is transpiled to this JavaScript file:

```
var TestClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TestClass() {
    }
    TestClass.prototype.execute = function () {
    };
    return TestClass;
}());
```

But neither IntelliSense nor Closure Compiler recognize this new type.  Even in the above JavaScript file, if I append `/**@type {TestClass}*/var x;`, `TestClass` is not recognized by IntelliSense when I put my mouse over it.  It just says, "any."  Closure Compiler says, "[JSC_UNRECOGNIZED_TYPE_ERROR] Bad type annotation. Unknown type TestClass."

How can I make TypeScript output JavaScript classes that IntelliSense and Closure Compiler can recognize?  I'm hoping I just need to decorate my TypeScript code with some JSDoc comments. I prefer to avoid Webpack and module statements.  I'm just testing out TypeScript on a small scale right now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to actually pass Typescript output to Closure Compiler, [tsickle](https://github.com/angular/tsickle) does exactly that. Also, you may want to use a wrapper [tscc](https://github.com/theseanl/tscc).